# Search posts that contain code

Tags: support, search

How to filter search in [TeX.SX](http://tex.stackexchange.com) to those have code in them. Also how to search inside the codes themselves.

Comment: Searching codes is something what browser provides, e.g. `CTRL-F` for Firefox ...

Answer (score 8):

Searching for posts that contains code can be achieved using the boolean operator `hascode`. More specifically, `hascode:` with `yes`/`true`/`1` returns only posts that contain code blocks; `no`/`false`/`0` returns only posts that contain *no* code.

Searching for posts where *inline* code (via backticks or `<code>`...`</code>` markdown) contains a specific `<string>` is achieved using `code:<string>`.

More search options are available from the [search help center](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/searching)

Answer (score 7):

Simply "hascode:yes", "hascode:1" or "hascode:true" should be added to search results.