# Retrieve a question from code

Tags: discussion, search

## Background

I read a question about adjusting the indentation of a list a few hours ago.  I've copied the following code found in the question.

```tex
\use{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{align=parleft,left=0pt..1em}
```

Later, I don't know why I can't find the question in my browsing history.  This leads me to finding a post with code.

## Initial problem

How can I find a post containing the 2nd line of the above code block?

## My try

Searching `"\setlist[itemize]{align=parleft,left=0pt..1em}"` (with double quotes) in the site's search box:
[https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q="%5Csetlist%5Bitemize%5D%7Balign%3Dparleft%2Cleft%3D0pt..1em%7D"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22%5Csetlist%5Bitemize%5D%7Balign%3Dparleft%2Cleft%3D0pt..1em%7D%22) gives me nothing.

[image: in site search no result]

## Solution

I googled `"\setlist[itemize]{align=parleft,left=0pt..1em}"`:
[https://www.google.com/search?q="%5Csetlist%5Bitemize%5D%7Balign%3Dparleft%2Cleft%3D0pt..1em%7D"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%5Csetlist%5Bitemize%5D%7Balign%3Dparleft%2Cleft%3D0pt..1em%7D%22), and I found [itemize, removing natural indent](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/91124/126386), which was what I had read.

[image]

## Refined problem

I would like to know how can I refine the in-site search so that I get the desired question.

Comment: `code:"\setlist[itemize]{align=parleft,left=0pt..1em}"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Search posts that contain code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6826)

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz thanks that worked :)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I would love to know how I can apply this to solve my problem.  I tried `hascode:yes "setlist[itemize]"`, but it didn't return the desired post: [https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=hascode%3Ayes+"setlist%5Bitemize%5D"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=hascode%3Ayes+"setlist%5Bitemize%5D")

Comment: That's very peculiar.  In the request shown by @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, the entire expression is included, and the match is found.  I would have assumed that a partial string, say "\setlist[itemize]", would pick that up plus a lot of  other posts -- but it doesn't, although more than 250 matches are found.  I think the search is limited in some way not explained in the search instructions linked from the post I cited.  If I have time, I'll try to formulate a question and post it on the "global" meta site.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Can you please ping me if you post such a question on main meta? I'd like to follow it

Comment: Note that, in general, search functionality is somewhat flaky. It's almost always better to use a Google search specific to the site in question. That is, `<your search query> site:tex.stackexchange.com`